# Spark groupBy agg not working as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, aggregate-functions

I am getting similar issue:

```
(df
    .groupBy("email")
    .agg(last("user_id") as "user_id")
    .select("user_id").count,
df
    .groupBy("email")
    .agg(last("user_id") as "user_id")
    .select("user_id")
    .distinct
    .count)
```

When run on one computer it gives: (15123144,15123144)

When run on cluster it gives:  (15123144,24)

The first one is expected and looks correct but second one is horribly wrong. One more observation - even if I change data where total count is more/less than 15123144 I get distinct = 24 on cluster. 
Even if I interchange user_id and email, it gives same distinct count.

I am more confused by seeing: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Agg doc says: Aggregates on the entire DataFrame without groups. "Without group"? what does that mean?

Any clue? or Jira ticket? or what can be fix for now?

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with "without group" part. As it is described in the docs:

> df.agg(...) is a shorthand for df.groupBy().agg(...)

If it is still not clear it translates to SQL:

```
SELECT SOME_AGGREGATE_FUNCTION(some_column) FROM table
```

Regarding your second problem it is hard to give you a good answer without an access to the data but generally speaking these two queries are not equivalent. The first simply counts distinct `email` values, the second one count unique values of the last `user_id` per email. Moreover `last` without explicit ordering is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks zero323, as I mentioned: When run on one computer it gives: (15123144,15123144) , and by data no email should repeat for different user_id and vice versa. That much I can say about the data. Sorry I am not able to share the sample data here.

Comment: Without explicit ordering (like in window functions) `last` is not meaningful so you can get different results depending on a configuration.  I would start with checking what you get after `df.groupBy(...) .agg(...).select(...) .distinct` on the cluster. It should give you some idea what is going on (are there any nulls / empty strings involved). Without a reproducible example (no one here want your real data) this questions, same as any opened JIRA, are simply a curiosity.

Comment: In log, I see: 15/12/11 17:43:20 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 23.0 in stage 14.0 (TID 795) in 671 ms on slave4.example.com (24/24) Is that related to 24 distinct value or we can make anything from this line from log?

Comment: Not much. Looks like it keeps a single value per partition. Could be some hashing  issue... Have tried above suggestion?

Comment: No null or empty strings with your suggestion. How can I track it to hashing, if its really a hashing issue?